# How to specify a list of dictionaries with duplicated values?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have my data divided into 3 columns, column 1 and 2 have duplicated values. I want to make a nested dictionary where column 1 corresponds to key1, column 2 to key 2 and column 3 to the value: my_dict[column1][column2] = column[3] (something like sort a matrix in excel by 2 levels). But I don't know how to deal with the key error at the second level.

my infile looks like:

```
string_1    val_1    2
string_1    val_2    4
string_2    val_1    3
string_2    val_1    2
string_2    val_1    2
string_3    val_3    1
string_3    val_2    2
```

```
for line in infile:
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    col = line.split('\t')
    try:
        filt_dic[col[1]] = {}
        filt_dic[col[1]][col[2]].append(col[3])
    except KeyError:
        filt_dic[col[1]] = {}
        filt_dic[col[1]][col[3]] = [col[3]]
```

Actually, it just appends the last value in the second level, I do not know how to specify that it is a list of dictionaries. It is not correct:

```
filt_dict[col[1]].appen({})
or
filt_dict[col[1]] = [{}]
```

I know which is the error but not how to solve this, some suggestions?

Comment: This is noramlly easier and faster using some tool like pandas and then filtering on DataFrame. The fundamental problem in your approach is that you ask for dictionaries and they require unique keys. In your case it seems that you can create unique keys by concatenating column1 and column2 to generate a single dictionary according to the following logic `my_dict['-'.join([column1, column2])] = column[3]`.

Comment: What about a dictionary whose keys are tuples consisting of 2 strings representing the first 2 columns? `filt_dic[col[0], col[1]] = col[2]`? Note: in *col*, indexes start from 0.

Comment: Can you show us an example of what you want the output to look like?

Comment: I was able to cook something up by playing around with your code! Check it out :) @fcalles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to achieve something close to what you were looking for using `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict

#Use a defaultdict of dictionaries
filt_dic = defaultdict(dict)

with open('file.txt') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        #Split on whitespace
        col = line.split()

        #Set default value for filt_dic[col[0]] and append col[2]
        filt_dic[col[0]].setdefault(col[1],[])
        filt_dic[col[0]][col[1]].append(col[2])

print(dict(filt_dic))
```

So if the file looks like

```
string_1    val_1   2
string_1    val_2   4
string_2    val_1   3
string_2    val_1   2
string_2    val_1   2
string_3    val_3   1
string_3    val_2   2
```

My output will be

```
{
'string_1': {'val_1': ['2'], 'val_2': ['4']},
'string_2': {'val_1': ['3', '2', '2']},
'string_3': {'val_3': ['1'], 'val_2': ['2']}
}
```

Observe that the lists at the 3rd level in the dict have more than one element sometimes, since key1 and key2 are same for some rows!

Comment: Sure thing! It was pure guesswork from the structure of the code, but glad to help :)